# How to extract prime numbers from a fibonacci series in C++?

Tags: c++, numbers, extract, primes, fibonacci

Please help my code is as follows. I have found out the Fibonacci series within a range successfully but I am finding it difficult to extract the prime numbers from the Fibonacci series. There seems to be a lot of bugs in the prime number part. Please help. Thanks

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
  clrscr();
  int n, c, first = 0, second = 1, next, flag;

  cout << "Enter the number of terms of Fibonacci series you want" << endl;
  cin >> n;

  cout << "First " << n << " terms of Fibonacci series are :- " << endl;

  for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
  {
    if (c <= 1)
      next = c;
    else
    {
      next = first + second;
      first = second;
      second = next;
    }
    cout << next << endl;
    for (int j = 2; j<next; j++)
    {
      if (next%j == 0)
      {
        flag++;
      }
      if (flag == 0)
      {
        cout << "Prime numbers are" << next << "\t";
      }
    }
    getch();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Updated as Rolland mentions, i edited so that sqrt is computed only once, and oh 1 is not prime, silly me*
Check for prime

```
#include <math.h>    
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return false;
    if (n == 2 || n == 3) return true;
    int checkRange = sqrt(n);
    for (int i = 2; i <= checkRange; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You then store them in a collection and use another loop to print it out

```
#include <vector> //Include this - vector is a standard c++ container

//Declare in your function
std::vector<int> primes;

//In your code where you get your next fibbonacci
if (isPrime(next))
   primes.push_back(next);

//After you finished looping for fibbonacci
cout << endl << "Prime numbers are" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++)
   cout << primes[i] << " ";
```

Update as OP requested: Fullcode, no vector
***Note:*** when extracting the primes, in order to output them separately with the fibbonacci you have to store them somewhere. Since you dont use vector, i'm gonna implement this with array.
The problem with array is, you have to declare them with a size, but you dont know how many primes you'll get at the moment you declare the it yet. So you'll have to declare the array with size large enough to contain all the primes in your fibbonacci

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 100
using namespace std;
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return false;
    if (n == 2 || n == 3) return true;
    int checkRange = sqrt(n);
    for (int i = 2; i <= checkRange; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
void main()
{
    int n, c, first = 0, second = 1, next, primeCount = 0;
    int primes[MAX];

    cout << "Enter the number of terms of Fibonacci series you want" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    cout << "First " << n << " terms of Fibonacci series are :- " << endl;

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
    {
        if (c <= 1)
            next = c;
        else
        {
            next = first + second;
            first = second;
            second = next;
        }

        cout << next << endl;

        if (isPrime(next)) //Reuse the above isPrime
        {
            primes[primeCount] = next;
            primeCount++;
        }
    }

    for (c = 0; c < primeCount; c++)
        cout << primes[c] << " ";
}
```

Comment: 1 is not a prime, and `sqrt` takes a long time to compute, so it should only be done once. Other than that, very nice. :)

Comment: Thank you @nmtuan .but can we do it without the vector.Would be more good if you provide the complete cpp program .

Comment: Probably one would prefer `i += 2` since it's meaningless to check if the number has an even divisor

Comment: Thanks mate @nmtuan but your #define MAX = 100 didn't work on my compiler Turbo C++.I modified it to #define MAX 100 to suit my compiler.Also inserted the isPrime function but still there's one  error left .Please help

Comment: I inserted the isPrime function just above the if(isPrime) line.But its showing statement missing ";" error .On imserting ; ,the error is not rectified.Please insert the isPrime function to your edited code so that i could find out where i did the mistake

Comment: ^Updated the code, a function should be written outside of another function scope - thats {...} for ya... Til ya get to learn a thing call lambda :D

Comment: @nmtuan still there is an error buddy.It says declaration syntax error.Must have something to do with bool .Can't u avoid bool ? As i read while going through some tutorials.it says turbo c and turbo c++ doesn't support bool.I would like to request you to please see if bool can be avoided

Comment: Hey bool is not supported by my compiler so i defined bool datatype by enumeration : typedef enum{false=0,true}bool; Thanks mate,finally its solved.Thank u very much

Comment: Also 1 question why have u computed the sqrt

Answer (score 1):

You might want to set `flag` to 0 first.